# Restore scroll position of specific page via history state

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I can go from a list view to a details view via history.push().
I want to remember the scroll position of my list to return there at anytime.

how can I save my state of the list and address it in my detail view, even when the link there has been changed?

```
code:

 navigateToDetails = () => {
        this.props.history.push(
            routes.details.url(this.key)
        )
    }
```

can i pass my location there? if yes, how can i access it in my details view?

Comment: This is a very general question. What have you tried to do? Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: background of the generality is that i have no clue where i should start. should i save the scroll position in redux? should i use anchors for the items?